# Perl Sort date and time inside csv file

Tags: perl, sorting, date

My file file.csv is having some columns among which column 1 represents date and time, I am trying to sort it by date and time but it is sorting only based on time. please check and suggest.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my $input_dir = "d://perl//output";
my $output_dir = "d://perl//output";
my $input_file = "$input_dir//file.csv";
my $output_file = "$output_dir//output2_file.csv";
open (OUTPUT, ">>$output_file") or die "Error 016: Error creating $out
+put_file \n";
open (INPUT, "<$input_file") or die "Error 001: Error locating file $i
+nput_file \n";

my @array =(<INPUT>);

#print "Array\n";
#@print join( "\n", @array )."\n\n";

print "Sort Date\n";
print join( "\n", @sortedTime )."\n\n";

 print OUTPUT;
close (OUTPUT);
    close (INPUT);
```

data in file.csv looks like

```
2016-02-02:00:44,mttsmshub1  
2016-02-05:00:39,mttsmshub1  
2016-02-03:00:32,tttsmshub1  
2016-02-04:00:24,mttsmshub1
```

current output looks like

```
2016-02-04:00:24,mttsmshub1  
2016-02-03:00:32,tttsmshub1  
2016-02-05:00:39,mttsmshub1  
2016-02-02:00:44,mttsmshub1
```

expected output should be

```
2016-02-02:00:44,mttsmshub1  
2016-02-03:00:32,tttsmshub1  
2016-02-04:00:24,mttsmshub1  
2016-02-05:00:39,mttsmshub1
```

Comment: Where you sort enything?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, I am new into perl, while executing above script you will see that it will sort based on time so "2016-02-04:00:24,mttsmshub1" becomes first row as it has the least time 00:24 but all i want is to sort it along with date. so what is want is sorting it date and timestamp wise.

Comment: First of all your code is not sorting anything. Second thing you are not clear about expecting output. Click on edit in question and add what you want as output.

Comment: updated question with current and expected output, check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not actually use the `sort` operator in your code. Secondly, the `print OUTPUT` line makes no sense... You are printing nothing to the `OUTPUT` filehandle.

Simply, just sort as soon as you slurp your `INPUT` filehandle, then print it to your `OUTPUT` filehandle

```
my @array = sort <INPUT>;
print OUTPUT @array;
```

There should be no need to use `join` at all. The lines in your array already have newlines that were already there in the `INPUT` file.